# EOF Exception when loading midi files

Tags: java, audio, midi

I'm taking .mid files used by a game, and generating drum tablature from them. It works fine for some .mid files, but others produce an EOFException

I'm using an extract of code, taken from [DumpSequence.java](http://www.jsresources.org/examples/DumpSequence.java.html)

```
Sequence sequence = null;
File midiFile = new File(strFilename);
sequence = MidiSystem.getSequence(midiFile);
```

(package is javax.sound.midi)

Error thrown:

> java.io.EOFException: invalid MIDI file
>     at com.sun.media.sound.SMFParser.readTrack(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileReader.getSequence(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileReader.getSequence(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequence(Unknown Source)
>     at DumpSequence.main(DumpSequence.java:125)

Can anyone point me in the right direction, on how to fix this? I've tried finding a solution, myself, but have come up empty.

Comment: When are you getting this error?

Comment: The program takes in a String for the midi path and filename. After checking if any other parameters have been passed in, the program then tries to load the midi file. This is when the error is thrown.

Comment: so its the : sequence = MidiSystem.getSequence(midiFile); line that throws the exception?

Comment: There are some midi file checkers in the net.

Comment: yeah, sorry, it's the .getSequence line.
Will look into a file checker.

Comment: Could you put that .mid file up somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few possibilities:

1. As the error message states, the MIDI file actually has an invalid format.
2. Byte ordering is different for this file, and not indicated in the file itself.
3. The version of Java (or the javax.sound library) you are using doesn't understand this MIDI file format.

You should be able to easily verify whether or not the file format is valid by playing it with a different MIDI file player. Then make sure that any other known-good Java MIDI program is able to process it.